# Number of handlers run from event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, queue, handler

Is it possible to get in C# when working with forms number of handlers ran ( or waiting in queue ) at the moment by chosen event?
For example: I have a lot of bars and they can be resized...so if I resize 4 then 4 times event runs. I need to get the last one when I resize multiple bars...

I'd like to check in barResizeHandler if number of events in queue is 0 then i can perform chosen action.

Comment: What is the problem? As I remember, all UI actions run in the same thread, so you can't resize elements until last resizing have been ended. As a consequence, each resizing is last.

Comment: Hmm. It's a pitty...

Comment: What is your real problem? Bad performance? Are 4 resizings so slow?

Comment: After resizing I have data reloading. I'd rather have it once on resizing. Bad you can resize 4 at once..

Answer (score 0):

Don't load data after resizing. Create cashe for you data, and after resizing take data from it.
For example,

`...
YourDataType[] _cashe = TakeDataFromSource(); // SaveDataToCashe
...
public void OnResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowDataInTheBars(_cashe); // Show data from the cashe
}`

Comment: Can you load all data to the cashe?
If no, don't reload ALL data after resizing. Load data, that haven't been loaded earlier. And, again, what is your real problem? Show your code  which loads data.